# Can an Unusual weapon be made a Strange Professional Killstreak weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Can I use make an Unusual weapon (that doesn't have a Killstreak, nor a Strange part) a Professional Killstreak and Strange?

Can I then apply war paint on top of that? Will that work?

Comment: Take a look at https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/War_Paint for info about how to obtain war painted items. If I'm not mistaken, you can only get new items by applying paint to a selection of all items listed for that paint, so you cannot apply it to any existing items. If this is correct, you can only start from a freshly painted item and then apply unusualifiers, strange counters and killstreak kits to it to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an unusual weapon strange and killstreak if you have a strangifier and a killstreak kit that match the base item type.

You can't change a weapon's paint, so you need to start off with the unusual painted weapon you want.

There are quite a few cases in which it won't work though:

- Not all war paints have unusual versions obtainable.
- Not all war paint weapons have strangifiers available for them.
- Not all war paint weapons have killstreak kits available for them. (I'm not actually 100% sure on this fact, and we might be able to still find generic killstreak kits for extremely high prices that apply to any item.)

Here's an example of one for sale that's Killstreak, Strange, and Unusual:

[image: screenshot of marketplace listing]

Note that it had to have started off with that war paint and effect since it was unboxed.